# AWS S3 cli: exclude not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I am using this cli:

```
aws s3 sync /home/me s3://meserver/test_me --exclude "*.o" --exclude "error_log" --exclude "access_log" --exclude "*.tgz" --exclude "*.tar.gz" --exclude "*.zip" --exclude "*.log" --exclude "*.tar"
```

The .zip and the sort exclude just fine. But `error_log` is not.

```
upload: ../../home/me/log/error_log to s3://meserver/testme/log/error_log
```

What am I missing? That is the exact filename.

Comment: Can you try `--exclude "*/error_log"`

Answer (score 1):

Your command is saying: `--exclude "error_log"`

However, the object that copied was `log/error_log`, because it does not match `error_log`.

Please note that the command uses paths and prefixes, rather than just filenames. The `key` of an object stored in Amazon S3 actually consists of the full path as well  as the name. Thus, `error_log` must be referenced in full.

You could exclude the file by using `--exclude "log/error_log"` or if you wish to exclude all such files, use `--exclude "*/error_log"`.

Comment: Yes.  Adding '*/' in front of your pattern is the solution.  I thought 'aws s3 sync' was supposed to work like rsync which would not require the '*/'.  Amazon's documentation shoud give an example to make this clear.

Comment: If I use --exclude "*/.DS_Store" all of my .DS_Store files still get operated on, according to dryrun.

Comment: Although ".DS_Store" and "*/.DS_Store" do not work as arguments to --exclude, "*.DS_Store" does work.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
aws s3 sync /home/me s3://meserver/test_me --exclude "\*.o" --exclude "\*/error_log" --exclude "access_log" --exclude "\*.tgz" --exclude "\*.tar.gz" --exclude "\*.zip" --exclude "\*.log" --exclude "\*.tar"
```